# Is there any specified way for makes a executable from python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, error-handling, module

Because of,  I done my python script to solve my problem,

and also I made a executable from the python file to run in windows,

using auto-py-to-exe module, but this working fine, approximately 6 times when i run the file 10 times,

All the depended files are in the same folder,

Other times that shows me, fatal error - Failed to execute Application file,

I don't know the actual problem behind this, I am also searching........... If anybody handle the issue already, kindly let me know the solution, thank you for all the supporters in advance.

Don't mind developers, actually I refer and try all that things with the pyinstaller, but nothing solved my issue, thatwhy I make the question.

Note: I using the python3 auto-py-to-exe module, in windows 10 pro(1803)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

Comment: Try pyinstaller or fbs. fbs recommended when you make pyqt5 or pyside2.